# An inverse of a function.

Tags: calculus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C8fe.jpg

Show that the function $f(x) = \dfrac x {1+x^2},\quad x\in[0,1],$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$ on $[0,1]$ and find its domain.

Actually, English is not my language and i have a question. i don't understand this question. What do it say? can anyone explain it to me?
i don't understand so i couldn't do it :/

thanks.

Comment: If you do not understand English well enough to understand what the question is asking as it is written now, how do you expect us to be able to explain it in such a way that you can understand using English as well?  Assuming your professor speaks the same language as you do, you should ask him/her instead of us.

Comment: you are right. but it is homework. and i dont have a time for asking to him. my math skill is good (i think). and i understand if i read a anything. so i ask it to this site. and i understand. but you right. i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that  function has an inverse, it is often useful to show it is strictly monotone (this is just the horizontal line test).

For your function, 
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}
$$
we can differentiate to find
$$
f'(x)=\frac{x^2+1-2x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}
$$
Noting that the domain in question is $[0,1]$, the denominator is always positive, and your function is increasing.

As for the domain of the function, it will be the range of your function for $x\in [0,1]$. By the same computation as in the above, we have a maximum at $1=x$, where $f=1/2$. The minimum is clearly $0$. By the intermediate value theorem, all points in between are hit by $f$.

Comment: thank you so much. your narration was be very clear for me. i understand clearly.